# Prove that $\int_0^t\frac{(B^1_s)^2}{\big((B_s^1)^2+(B_s^2)^2+(B_s^3)^2\big)^3}ds<\infty $ a.s.

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

Let $(B^1,B^2,B^3)$ a Brownian motion in $\mathbb R^3$. Prove that $$\int_0^t\frac{(B^1_s)^2}{\big((B_s^1)^2+(B_s^2)^2+(B_s^3)^2\big)^3}ds<\infty \quad  a.s.$$

---

I'm not so sure how to do it. Set $f(x,y,z)=\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^3}$. I proved that $$m\{s\in [0,t]\mid (B_s^1)^2+(B_s^2)^2+(B_s^3)^2=0\}=0\ \ a.s.$$
therefore $f(B_s^1,B_s^2,B_s^3)<\infty $ a.s. But unfortunately, this doesn't prove the claim. Moreover, since $f(B_s^1,B_s^2,B_s^3)$ is not a.s. bounded on $[0,t]$, I don't know how to do. Any idea ?

Comment: The integrand is well defined and takes values in $[0,1]$ except at those times when the denominator vanishes. Can you show that the probability that the denominator vanishes for even one time is $0$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins: No, why does $\mathbb P\{\exists s\in (0,t)\mid (B^1_s)^2+(B^2_s)^2+(B^3_s)^2=0\}=0$ ? Also, why $\frac{(B_s^1)^2}{((B^1_s)^2+(B^2_s)^2+(B^3_s)^2)^3}\in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Because a Brownian motion in dimension 3 (or even dim. 2) doesn't hit a pre-selected point (like the origin), with probability one.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Ok. And why $\frac{(B_s^1)^2}{(B_s^1)^2+(B_s^2)^2+(B_s^3)^2)^3}\in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Because $a^2 \le a^2+b^2+c^2$ for any three real numbers $a,b,c$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: But this will not implies that $a^2\leq (a^2+b^2+c^2)^3$. For example, take $a=0.5$, $b=c=0$, then $(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3\leq a^2$.

Comment: Somehow I missed the 3 in the exponent!  In fact, I think the integral diverges, a.s. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

If the given integral is finite a.s., then so are the integrals with $(B_s^2)^2$ and $(B_s^3)^2$ in the numerator instead of $(B_1^1)^2$. Adding these three integrals one finds that
$$
\int_0^t {1\over \left((B^1_s)^2+(B_s^2)^2+(B_s^3)^2\right)^2}\,ds<\infty, a.s.
$$
Now the radial part $R_t:=\sqrt{(B^1_s)^2+(B_s^2)^2+(B_s^3)^2}$ of a 3-dimensional Brownian motion, the so-called 3-dim. Bessel process, has been well studied. In particular, it is known that if $f:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ is (for simplicity) continuous, then $\int_0^t f(R_s)\,ds<\infty$ for all $t>0$ a.s.  if and only if $\int_0^1 rf(r)\,dr<\infty$. [See https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0083762 , "A zero-one law for integral functionals of the Bessel process" by Xing-Xiong Xue.] In the present case, $f(r) = r^{-4}$, for which $\int_0^1 rf(r)\,dr =\int_0^1 r^{-3}\,dr =\infty$. So the Brownian integral in question cannot converge.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1$ be your function. Let $f_2$ and $f_3$ be the same except with $y$ and $z$ on top.  By symmetry, it is now enough to find $$\int_0^t \sum_i f_i(B^1_s,B^2_s,B^3_s)ds=\int_0^t ||(B^1_s,B^2_s,B^3_s)||^{-2}ds$$

A nonnegative random variable on a probability space is bounded a.s. iff its expectation is finite. So taking expectation and applying Fubini, we get,

$$\int_0^t\mathbb{E}\left[||(B^1_s,B^2_s,B^3_s)||^{-2}\right]ds$$

So now you just need to understand $$\mathbb{E}\left[||(B^1_s,B^2_s,B^3_s)||^{-2}\right] $$ as a function of s.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit ? Because I don't see how to conclude.